# 2003 can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' 10013 using navicat

Tags: mysql, xampp, navicat

I am trying to create connection to mysql using Navicat but I am getting this error. 
I am using following settings 
Host/Ip Address: localhost
Port: 3306
UserName: root
Password:

Comment: [Refer](https://help.navicat.com/hc/en-us/articles/217790698-2003-Can-t-connect-to-MySQL-server-on-xxx-10061-)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can Whether it is right by checking `user&password`
2. Try changing localhost to 127.0.0.1
   Actually,I think only you can sign in by `Mysql` client then the same in `Navicat` work.

Comment: In your mysql terminal,Can you Sign in? Maybe you can try Create other user